# How to get straight table values or table data into an variable in Qlikview?

Tags: qlikview, pptxgenjs

How to get straight table values or table data into an variable in Qlikview ?
As I am going to use the table data in Javascript fetched through variable and generate PPT reports using pptxgenjs library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something like `let MyVar = peek(...)` ([see documentation for peek() here](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/qlikview/12.1/Subsystems/Client/Content/Scripting/InterRecordFunctions/Peek.htm)).

If you need to merge values from multiple fields you should do that first using the scripting function `concat()` to load those values into a string in a new (temporary) table, and use peek on that table.